# How to get information about the client in node.js

Tags: javascript, real-time, node.js

in this very simple example:

```
var sys = require("sys"),
    http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.end("Hello World!");
}).listen(8080);

sys.puts("Server running at http://localhost:8080/");
```

1.) What kind of information can I get from the client? like browser, screen resolution, etc?

2.) How can I send information from the client to server, like parameter?

thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't get the screen resolution information, but you can get the user agent from Request Header "User-Agent"

Comment: What is the code necessary for this? I have tried req.getHeader('User-Agent') but don't think that works.

Comment: @zzaman try req.headers['user-agent'] - all the headers in node [are lowercase](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_request_headers).

Answer (score 23):

1) Referrer URL, IP address, User Agent, screen size and other [stats](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_screen.asp).
You can also get geo location but that is more involved.

2) Some data is available in the headers so these are sent on every request - other data such as screen size is a little trickier so you'll want to make an ajax request to send that along.

```
// Somewhere on your page(s) - here we use jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){   
  // Check if they have been logged
  if ($.cookie('logged') == null ){
    // Send screen size and whatever else that is not available from headers
    $.post('/logger', { width: screen.width, height: screen.height }, function(res) {
      // Set cookie  for 30 days so we don't keep doing this
       $.cookie('logged', true, { expires: 30 }); 
    });
  } 
 });  

// Server side - example is an Express controller
exports.logger = function(req, res) {
  var user = {
    agent: req.header('user-agent'(, // User Agent we get from headers
    referrer: req.header('referrer'), //  Likewise for referrer
    ip: req.header('x-forwarded-for') || req.connection.remoteAddress, // Get IP - allow for proxy
    screen: { // Get screen info that we passed in url post data
      width: req.param('width'),
      height: req.param('height')
    }
  };
  // Store the user in your database
  // User.create(user)...
  res.end();
}
```

Comment: For `referrer`, browsers [will send](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer#Etymology) `referer` with a single R. Express does not translate that to the proper spelling, so the above needs `req.headers['referer']`.

Comment: @Arjan they are interchangeable. Express can handle ether one. https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/request.js#L76

Comment: That's weird, as I tested before posting that comment (and even added a comment in my code explaining Express does not translate...). Will check again tomorrow, but your link doesn't lie... :-)

Comment: Ah, in your comment you're referring to the (nice) helper function `header('referrer')` (which is an alias for [`req.get('referrer')`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.get) which indeed handles both `referer` and `referrer`. However, in your answer you're accessing the request property `headers` directly, `req.headers['referrer']`, which yields `undefined`. ;-)

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for catching that. I have updated answer to use the helper function.

Answer (score 6):

Have you read the [API docs](http://nodejs.org/api/)?  The req object is a http.ServerRequest object as documented there.  It's HTTP, and such things like resolution are not part of the protocol.  What you can get is a user-agent, and from there you might be able to retrieve more information using another service.

Remember that node.js is a standalone app - it's not running in a browser - it's an HTTP Server application that is running in a JS interpreter.